# How to remove attr when mouseout?

Tags: jquery, html

On my page when mouse over it will add attribute of checked checked for the input type radio how to add mouseout inside mouse over to remove the attribute?

```
   $('span').mouseover(function(){
     jQuery(this).find('input').attr('checked','checked')
 });
```

Comment: `$('span').mouseout(function(){
     jQuery(this).find('input').removeAttr('checked'')
 });`

Comment: all of your answers worked but when mouseover again it will not be checked i used prop rather and it worked sorry guys may be i dont know how to figure it out and ask attribute. my bad

Comment: i think you need mouse in mouse out  . on mouse over attr checked and triggered mouse out function so it's unchecked again seamless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this in single function using `event`.

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'span', function(evt) {
  evt.type === 'mouseenter' ? $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true) : $(this).find('input').prop('checked', false);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" >
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `attr('checked','checked')`, use this:

```
.attr('checked',true);  // to make checked
.attr('checked',false); // to make uncheck
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ev81Lm34/)

In your case use to make it unchecked on `mouseout` try this:

```
$('span').mouseout(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('input').attr('checked',false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeAtrr('checked')` for removing attribute `checked` when mouseout.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ev81Lm34/5/)

HTML Code-

```
<span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" >
</span>
<span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" checked >
</span>
```

JAVASCRIPT Code-

```
$('span').mouseout(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('input').removeAttr('checked');
});
$('span').mouseover(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('input').attr('checked','checked')
});
```